LibreOffice opens unwanted toolbars on new files
Whenever I open a new .doc or .docx file (typically downloaded from the Internet, or attached to email I have received), LibreOffice opens a lot of toolbars, cluttering my window and reducing the available space. 
Even though I close those toolbars, they are opened again on the next opening.
How can I tell LibreOffice to open only the toolbars I want
(just a couple of them)?
UPDATE:  As usual. trying to reliably reproduce an error which you have experienced for ages makes the bug disappear. Which means that I should have reported it earlier :)
Thanks to the gentle souls who have cared to comment. I'll come back when I see it again.

You might get less clutter if you open the document in read-only mode. Try the option --view on the command line.

Since the documents are typically downloaded from the net, please provide a link to a sample document on the net that causes the problem for one to test.
